# Default Maps app in iPhone Simulator cannot determine location

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I am trying to test out some basic CoreLocation functions, and when playing around with the default Maps app I discovered that it is unable to determine my location using the small triangle icon on the left hand corner.  I tried restarting the simulator several times, as well as resetting the simulator's contents and settings, but so far none hasn't worked.  Is there a setting that I still need to enable in the Simulator?

Comment: Did you set a location in Xcode (part of the debugging tools)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Xcode doesn't simulate any location while the simulator is running. You can ask it to simulate, you can set the initial location and you can change the location while the app is running. Check the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible for the Simulator to get my real current location, or must all locations be set under the debugging menu?

Comment: No, you need to be running on a device to get your true location.